# Hide AJAX Cart item numers if no item in cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, shopping-cart

I'm struggling with some javascript to figure out the proper way to make it work.

I have a button showing the number of items in the cart. By default is zero. As items added the cart the number is increasing. But at the beginning, I don't want to show "0" in the cart.

HTML:

```
<p id="cart_button" onclick="show_cart();">
  <input type="button" id="total_items" value="0">
</p>

<div id="mycart"></div>

<div id="item_div">

  <div class="items" id="item1">
    <input type="button" value="Add To CART" onclick="cart('item1')">
    <p>Simple Navy Blue T-Shirt</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="item1_name" value="ITEM-ID1">
  </div>

  <div class="items" id="item2">
    <input type="button" value="Add To CART" onclick="cart('item2')">
    <p>Trendy T-Shirt With Back Design</p>
    <input type="hidden" id="item2_name" value="ITEM-ID2">
  </div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'store_items.php',
    data: {
      total_cart_items: "totalitems"
    },
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value = response;
    }
  });
});

function cart(id) {
  var name = document.getElementById(id + "_name").value;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'store_items.php',
    data: {
      item_name: name
    },
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value = response;
    }
  });
}

function show_cart() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'store_items.php',
    data: {
      showcart: "cart"
    },
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("mycart").innerHTML = response;
      $("#mycart").slideToggle();
    }
  });
}
```

I basically want the button with 0 to be hidden until it gets a value. if it goes back to zero I want it to be hidden again.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can show/hide when update cart:

```
// Add this function
function update_cart(value) {
  document.getElementById("total_items").value = response;

  if (value > 0) {
    // Show the cart
    document.getElementById("total_items").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    // Hide the cart
    document.getElementById("total_items").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Then, you need to change your code, when update cart:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'store_items.php',
  data: {
    total_cart_items: "totalitems"
  },
  success: function(response) {
    update_cart(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: He is using jquery, why not just use `$("#total_items").show();` and `$("#total_items").hide();` ...

Comment: He is getting elements using `document.getElementById`, in case of doubt, I have put the form that will always work. It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'change' event listener to this button:

```
let totalItems = $('#total_items');

totalItems.change(function () {
  if (totalItems.val() == 0) {
    totalItems.hide();
  }
  else totalItems.show();
});
```

Also you should trigger this event in your success method of ajax:

```
success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("total_items").value = response;
      totalItems.change();
    }
```

And finally hide this button at start:

```
<input type="button" id="total_items" value="0" style="display: none">
```

Check this working in fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/771844/